# Cannot click the element after swipe in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I tested on Amazon shopping app. I have an issue after swipe to find an element.
Because the list view is too long. I need to scroll (using the swipe API). But after I swipe, I cannot click the element anymore. It returned no error but the app have no responses.

The function ScrollToElement() is to swipe to search element. I tried to use touch action tap but no hope. I tried to tap an exact(372,466) location and it works but it is not as expected. Thanks in advance.

```
public class FirstTest {
   private AppiumDriver driver;
   private   Dimension size;

   @BeforeClass
   public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException {


      String appActivityText = "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity";


      String appPackageText = "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping";

      String fileLocation = "/system/app/";

      File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
      File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "\\STC");
      File app = new File(appDir, fileLocation);
      System.out.println(app);
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");

      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "420373d0de528100");//420373d0de528100 01a61316598f30e6

      capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "100");

      // capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome"/*app.getAbsolutePath()*/);

      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", appPackageText);

      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", appActivityText);

      driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   }

   @Test
   public void Login() throws Exception {
      // Click on Shop by Deparment link
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Click on Shop by Deparment link");
      driver.findElement(By.id("web_home_shop_by_department_label")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);

      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Office Products Link"));
      ScrollToElement(driver, element);

      Thread.sleep(3000);
//      TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
//      action.tap(372,466).perform();

      driver.findElement(By.name("Office Products Link")).click();

   }
   @AfterClass
   public void closeApp() {
      // driver.closeApp();

   }

public static void ScrollToElement(AppiumDriver driver, WebElement element){
      size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

      // Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
      // Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
      int start = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
      int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
      // Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
      int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
      // Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of
      // screen width.
      int startx = size.width / 2;

      while (true) {
         driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
         start = start + (starty - endy);
         if (element.getLocation().getY() - start < size.height - endy) {
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you use `driver.findElement` incorrectly. 
Let me explain. `driver.findElement` inspects the elements presented on the screen, if it's found, it will return it.

The problem with your code is that you do `driver.findElement` before the scrolling function, which means that that if the element is not currently on screen, the test will always fail.

this code block should help you:

```
public WebElement findItemWithScrollingUsingBy(By by, int interactions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < interactions; i++) {
        if (driver.findElements(by).size() == 0) {
            scrollDown();
        } else {
            return driver.findElement(by); //you can add .click() here instead of returning the element
        }
    }
    Assert.fail("Element not found");
    return null;
}
```

the function `scrollDown()` is just to take the code-block of the swipe to an external function, which is much cleaner.

To sum up my answer:

1. Search on screen for the element - if found, click
2. If not found - make another scroll action and search for the element again
3. repeat

Comment: Actually. The element what I want to find is already presented but it is located at bottom of the list view. I use the API getsize(), driver.findElement(By.name("Office Products Link")).getsize().
It returned a value. But I cannot click the element too. Because of that, I tried to scroll the screen to present the element.
I have no idea with this, but thanks for your helps

Comment: If the element is located at the bottom of the screen, then you need to do another scroll after you've found the element. What you can do is - `slowScroll() ` with `starty  = ... * 0.6 ` and `endy = ... * 0.4 `.after this scroll the item will be at the middle of the screen - ready to be clicked.

you can also perform tap() on the top part of the element using its coordinates. But first let's try this one.

Comment: Thanks David, but I am a newbie with appium. "perform tap() on the top part of the element using its coordinates" what does it mean? Can you guide me?

Comment: The extra scroll didn't work?
`driver.tap(1,x,y,1)` is a function used to click on the screen using coordinates. so, take the coordinates of the element like this: Hight: `int y = element.getRect().getY()` Middle of the element: `int x = element.getRect().getX() + element.getRect().getWidth()/2`
and now `driver.tap(1,x,y+10,1) // + 10 pixels so the coordinate is inside the element` means that you will be tapping at the middle at the very top of the element.